# Why does a right-tailed distribution have a positive third moment?

Tags: probability, statistics

So a right-tailed distribution (or a left-leaning one) has positive skewness, which means a positive third moment. I was trying to convince myself why this is always the case. I am considering a compactly supported discrete distribution for simplicity. Now a typical right-tailed distribution will have its mode and most of the frequency concentrated towards the left, dragging the mean to a bit left of where it would have been for a uniform distribution. So that there are more positive terms in the sum $$\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^3f_i$$ than negative terms. But the median is to the left of $\bar x$, which means there is more frequency associated with the negative terms than the positive ones. Why is  it always the case then, that this sum ends up positive? I am guessing that the third powers of the higher magnitude terms end up on top but I am not very convinced.

Comment: $$ x_1=1,\quad x_2=1,\quad x_3=1,\quad x_4 = 5 $$
Here the mean is $2$ and the median is $1.$ The third central moment is
$$\begin{align}
& \frac{(1-2)^3 + (1-2)^3 + (1-2)^3 + (5-2)^3} 4 \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac {-1-1-1+ 27} 4 = 6>0.
\end{align}$$
The negative part gets $3/4$ of the probability; the positive part only $1/4$ and yet the latter prevails. Part of the answer is how fast the cubing function grows: $3^3 \gg 1^3. \qquad$

Comment: [It's not true in general](http://jse.amstat.org/v13n2/vonhippel.html).

Comment: @J.G. which part?

Comment: @J.G. : When you say "it" is not true in general, what is "it"? I am _guessing_ that what you mean is that it is not in general true that when the third moment is positive, then the mean exceeds the median. But why should I have to guess? Can't you just say that simply, if that's what you mean? And if it isn't what you mean, then what is?

Comment: @MichaelHardy My "it" is the OP's "this".

Comment: @J.G. : The OP's uses the word "this" twice: The first one seems to mean "a right-tailed distribution (or a left-leaning one) has positive skewness, which means a positive third moment." That leaves me wondering whether the OP intended "right-tailed" to mean only that the mean exceeds the median, so it's still not clear. The second use of "this" is in the following: "But the median is to the left of x¯, which means there is more frequency associated with the negative terms than the positive ones. Why is it always the case then, that this sum ends up positive?" $\qquad$

Comment: @J.G. : $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$ So that second "this" seems to mean if the mean exceeds the median, then the third central moment is positive. Is that what you meant by "it"? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy By right-tailed I meant positively skewed.

Comment: @HritRoy : And by "positively skewed", you mean the third central moment is positive?

Comment: @MichaelHardy of course I don't want to have a circular reasoning. Could you maybe explain what you mean by "positive skewness"? Positive third central moment should be a conclusion I draw from it.